# selecting nodes with same name in jstree

Tags: javascript, jstree

I am using jstree and several nodes in my tree have the same name. If i am selecting a node with name 'aaa', i want all nodes with name 'aaa' to be selected.

$j("#actionButtonTest").click(function() {

```
  $j("#demo2")
   .bind("select_node.jstree", function (e, data) {
    alert(data.rslt.obj.attr("name")); //alerts node name
    data.inst.select_node($j('li[name="situ"]')); //selects node with name 'situ' -- not working though
    $j.jstree.select_node($j('li[name="situ"]')); ////selects node with name 'situ' -- not working though
    });

});
```

I would be grateful if somebody could show me the right way of selecting all nodes with a particular selected name.

Cheers

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think jstree is written to select 1 node at a time by code. Try this:

```
.bind("select_node.jstree", function (e, data) {
    var inst = data.inst;

    $("#treeview").find('li').each(function (k, v) {
        inst.select_node(v);
    });

});
```

Comment: Updated a example which is working on my website, selecting all the nodes of the tree.

Comment: Thank you so much, it is now selecting all nodes. I guess i need to modify the 'find' arguments to select only a node with a particular name